# How convert QNetworkCookie to QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to convert QNetworkCookie to QString but I can't find a way how to do this.
For example, I've tried to do something like this

```
QString cookie = QVariant(cookies_[i]).toString();
```

and this

```
QString cookie = (QString*)cookies_[i];
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: A quick look at `QNetworkCookie` has documentation for `QByteArray QNetworkCookie::value()`. This will give you a `QByteArray` which you can convert to `QString`.

Comment: @Aditya thanks! I'll check it :)

Comment: @Aditya hello again! Thanks for the help before. The problem is solved, but as scopchanov said, if you want to, please, write the answer to the question. If you don't, I will mark my answer as a problem solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do proceed with marking your answer as solution. I didn't write up an answer because I didn't know enough about `QNetworkCook` in general. But glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aditya told, QNetworkCookie::value() works as QByteArray.
So, problem solvetion for me is:

```
auto cookie = reply->manager()->cookieJar()->cookiesForUrl(webReportsUrl);//).value(0);
cookies = cookie[0].name() + "=" + cookie[0].value() + "; domain=" + cookie[0].domain() + "; path=" + cookie[0].path();
qDebug() << "Cookie: " << cookies;
```

But presented returns only cookies' value without a name, domain, and others.

Comment: Two things are wrong in this post. 1. If a comment from a user has helped you find a solution, ask the user to write an answer and accept/upvote it. 2. If you have further problems, either edit your question to add more details, or if it is not a minor clarification, ask another question.

Comment: @scopchanov That is okay in my opinion. I don't feel the need for create on this one :)